# file manipulation in c++

Tags: c++, file

I convert this code in python to c++:

```
content = file(filename, "rb").read()
```

this is the code in c++:

```
ifstream file;
file.open(filename, fstream::binary);

file.seekg (0, ios::end);
long fileLength = file.tellg();
file.seekg(0, ios_base::beg);

char *content = new char[fileLength];
file.read(content, fileLength);
```

when I run the python code I get a long string in the content (500 characters~) while the c++ code return only 4 characters.

any suggestion?

thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "return"? What does `if (file)` say after you open the file?

Comment: no problem when opening the file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way to read an entire file is:

```
std::string content(
    std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(std::ifstream(filename, std::fstream::binary).rdbuf()),
    std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());
```

Comment: There's no need for `rdbuf()` there, I believe.

Comment: I don't think it will compile otherwise.  The constructor of `std::istreambuf_iterator` takes either a `streambuf*` or an `istream&`.  Since the `istream` form takes a reference to a non-const, it can't be initialized with a temporary.  (Of course, you probably want to open the file separately, in order to do some reasonable error handling if the open fails.  And in that case, you'll need an lvalue `ifstream`, which can be used to initialize the `istreambuf_iterator`.)

Comment: Ah yes, I didn't notice there's a temporary, sorry.